# Android web view and html multiselect dropdown

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have html page with multiselect drop down

HTML Code.

```
<select multiselect>

<option>0 months</option>
<option>12 months</option>
<option>13 monhts</option>
<option>14 months</option>

</select>
```

This is showed in android web view

This shows first option(0 months) in label,But i want to show 'Select age' as label .

I tried disabled attribute  in 1st option

```
<option disabled>Select age</option>
<option>12 months</option>
<option>13 monhts</option>
```

,but this does not shows in label

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
<select multiselect>
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" hidden="hidden">Select Age</option>
<option>0 months</option>
<option>12 months</option>
<option>13 monhts</option>
<option>14 months</option>

</select>
```

Comment: sorry to ear that, this plugin (which one is it ?) own be doing something on it's own with the select tag ...

Comment: This is a good solution for Android. Sadly doesn't work as well in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiselect>
    <optgroup label="Select Age"></optgroup>
    <option>0 months</option>
    <option>12 months</option>
    <option>13 monhts</option>
    <option>14 months</option>
</select>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.